# Error "some required macros where not defined" when trying to use boost in C++Builder

Tags: android, boost, c++builder

I wanted to use `boost::asio::serial_port` in a project for the Android platform, but got the following error from the `auto_link.hpp` file of the boost library:

> some required macros where not defined (internal logic error).

What macro are you required to define to use boost?

Comment: If you actually look in `auto_link.hpp`, you will see that error message is emitted if any of the following macros are not defined: `BOOST_LIB_NAME`, `BOOST_LIB_PREFIX`, `BOOST_LIB_TOOLSET`, `BOOST_LIB_THREAD_OPT`, `BOOST_LIB_RT_OPT`, `BOOST_LIB_ARCH_AND_MODEL_OPT`, `BOOST_LIB_VERSION`.  What steps exactly are you taking to use boost when this error happens? What does your code look like? Maybe you are simply missing a required header include.

Comment: It is enough to add #include <boost/asio/serial_port.hpp> to the newly created FMX project and select Android as the target platform (there is no error for the Windows platform).

Comment: I don't know what to tell you then. I don't use Boost myself. You should [file a bug report](https://quality.embarcadero.com) with Embarcadero.

Comment: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-34547